# Sum a list of string based on rule

Tags: python, string, list

I have a huge python list as the following example:

```
ls = ['name: John', 'John has ', '4 yellow ', 'cars.', 'name: Angelina', 'Angelina has ', '5 yellow', 'cars.']
```

I would like to join this information in this formatting:

```
ls = ['name: John', 'John has 4 yellow cars.', 'name: Angelina', 'Angelina has 5 yellow cars.']
```

I have tried this code

```
  with open ('names.txt', 'r') as text:  
    lines = text.readlines()
    for index,line in enumerate(lines):
        if not linha.startswith('name:'):
            ls2.append(lines[index]+lines[index+1])
```

But it was not good, since I have something like:

```
ls = ['name: John', 'John has 4 yellow', '4 yellow cars.', 'cars.name: Angelina']
```

Do you have any idea how can I perform this task?

Comment: What is the format of the file and what are the rules for joining? Your code suggests something with `startswith('name:')`, but since your code isn't working, we can't take that as specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
import itertools

ls = ['name: John', 'John has ', '4 yellow ', 'cars.', 'name: Angelina', 'Angelina has ', '5 yellow', 'cars.']

g = itertools.groupby(ls, lambda x: x.startswith('name: '))
output = [''.join(v) for _, v in g]
print(output) # ['name: John', 'John has 4 yellow cars.', 'name: Angelina', 'Angelina has 5 yellowcars.']
```

It groups the items by whether each item starts with `'name: '`;

1. Items that start with `'name: '` form a group (i.e., `['name: John']`).
2. Next a few items that don't do so form a group (i.e., `['John has ', '4 yellow ', 'cars.']`).
3. Next items that do so form another group (`['name: Angelina']`).
4. ... and so on alternatingly.

Then `join` concatenates the strings in each group.

Comment: Angelina should have `yellow cars`, not `yellowcars`.

Comment: That's because the input given by the OP has `'5 yellow'`, not `'5 yellow '`, as opposed to other items given such as `'4 yellow '` or `'John has '`. I assumed it is a typo by OP.

Comment: Ok, maybe typo. Although I'd find it rather weird if lines actually ended with spaces. Anyway, I just tried their own code and realized that they're of course completely lying about getting anything like their claimed output with that. They actually get a name error, after that's fixed they get an index error, and after that's fixed their result contains newlines and more elements than they've shown. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all the lines that don't begin with `name:` in a variable, then append that to the result when you get to the next `name:` line.

```
ls2 = []
temp_string = ''
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line.startswith('name:'):
        if temp_string:
            ls2.append(temp_string)
            temp_string = ''
            ls2.append(line)
    else:
        temp_string += line
# append the last set of lines
if temp_string:
    ls2.append(temp_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic can be better expressed as "if the current line begins with `name:`, then append it to a new list, and also join the next three lines into one line and append that line too."

```
with open ('names.txt', 'r') as text:  
    lines = text.readlines()

i = 0
ls2 = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('name:'):
        ls2.append(line)
        ls2.append(lines[i+1] + lines[i+2] + lines[i+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't split into all lines but just split the whole file by name lines and polish the whitespace afterwards?

```
import re
with open('names.txt') as f:
    ls = [re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s.strip())
          for s in re.split('(name:.*)', f.read())
          if s]
```

Writing your list back to file and using my above code, I get exactly the desired output (with spaces where they should be but no duplicate spaces):

```
['name: John', 'John has 4 yellow cars.', 'name: Angelina', 'Angelina has 5 yellow cars.']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZA9T8MwEEB3/4qTOtimxQsgoUodWFk7QocANjnJta07R2l/fcglpYDEllvuS@@ke@Vc25zuHgsNw@p2QagV7H3tilp2RUWGHbzo1Bz9Fp5zm/QGtGRoGwZp7uHsY8z91Lw3xE6KGXhKnz5iamTyXV/Bhwv4wx1Uj7WFXHwy0wV29VRl32sLIxa2CsYImWA85QETRJ5nEoUwVSObDQSMfhesUos15thVzGmpSTyWTBXI///k7/9m6eQdd2@G9CuvxYFIY8eVsBhrr0/POlhcCFEiVqPN5N/d2JEJjnzz8RfBAHxQ6iKM7TB8AQ)